# Issue with react-native FlatList rendering data when updating array of objects maintained in redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm loading a dynamic form in a FlatList. I'm supposed to add few rows with UI elements such as TextInput, checkbox, etc. based on a condition. For example, I have a dropdown, when I select a value, I have to add a row with a button and remove that row when I select another value.

My issue is that whenever I select a value in the dropdown to add a row with button, FlatList is adding duplicate rows and they are not visible as objects in my array when I debug them. I'm using Redux to manage my application state and updating my array in reducers.

I have to display objects in my array in FlatList without any duplicates using Redux for state management.

Code:

```
<FlatList
    key={Math.floor(Math.random())}
    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
    data={this.state.mainArray}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
    keyExtractor={({ item, id }) => String(id)}
    extraData={this.prop}
    keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
   scrollEnabled={true}
   removeClippedSubviews={false}
   scrollsToTop={false}
   initialNumToRender={100}
  />

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.setState({mainArray: nextProps.mainArray});

}
```

Updating array in Reducer:

```
case VALIDATE_DEPENDENCY: {
    // adding or removing dependency questions
    let dependingQues = [];
    let formArrayTemp = [...state.mainArray];
    let exists;
    // console.log("formArrayTemp123", formArrayTemp);
    if (action.item.isDependentQuestion) {
        if (action.item.dependentQuestionsArray.length > 0) {
            let dependent_ques = action.item.dependentQuestionsArray[0];
            state.depending_questions_array.filter((obj, id) => {
                if (JSON.stringify(obj.key_array) === JSON.stringify(dependent_ques.key)) {
                    dependingQues.push(obj);
                }
            });
            // console.log("dependingQues123", dependingQues);
            if (dependent_ques.answer === action.item.answer) {
                dependingQues.map((obj, id) => {
                    exists = formArrayTemp.filter((res, idx) => {
                        if (JSON.stringify(res.key_array) === JSON.stringify(obj.key_array)) {
                            return res;
                        }
                    });
                    // console.log("exists123", exists);
                    if (exists.length === 0) {
                        formArrayTemp.splice(action.index + id + 1, 0, obj);
                        // console.log("mjkgthbythyhy", action.index + id + 1);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                let objIndex = formArrayTemp.findIndex(obj => JSON.stringify(obj.key_array) === JSON.stringify(dependent_ques.key));
                if (objIndex !== -1) {
                    formArrayTemp[objIndex].answer = "";
                    formArrayTemp[objIndex].borderColor = "black";
                    formArrayTemp.splice(objIndex, 1);
                    // console.log("frtg6hyjukiu", formArrayTemp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // adding or removing dependent sections
    let dependentSections = [];
    let tempArr = [];
    let count = 0;
    if (action.item.isDependent) {
        if (action.item.dependentArray.length > 0) {
            let dependent_section = action.item.dependentArray[0];
            state.dependent_sections_array.filter((obj, id) => {
                if (obj.section_id === dependent_section.section_id) {
                    dependentSections.push(obj);
                }
            });
            // console.log("dependentSections123", dependentSections);
            let lastIndex;
            formArrayTemp.filter((res, id) => {
                if (action.item.section_id === res.section_id && res.dependentArray &&
                    JSON.stringify(action.item.dependentArray) === JSON.stringify(res.dependentArray)) {
                    tempArr.push(res);
                    lastIndex = formArrayTemp.FindLastIndex(a => a.section_id === res.section_id);
                }
            });
            // console.log("lastIndex123", lastIndex);
            tempArr.map((obj, id) => {
                if (obj.answer === obj.dependentArray[0].answer) {
                    count++;
                }
            });
            if (dependent_section.answer === action.item.answer) {
                dependentSections.map((obj, id) => {
                    if (formArrayTemp.contains(obj) === false) {
                        formArrayTemp.splice(lastIndex + id + 1, 0, obj);
                        // console.log("cfrererfre", formArrayTemp);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                let countTemp = [];
                if (count === 0) {
                    let countTemp = [];
                    dependentSections.filter((res, id) => {
                        if (formArrayTemp.contains(res) === true) {
                            formArrayTemp.filter((obj, idx) => {
                                if (obj.section_id === res.section_id) {
                                    obj.answer = "";
                                    obj.borderColor = "black";
                                    countTemp.push(obj);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    let jobsUnique = Array.from(new Set(countTemp));
                    formArrayTemp = formArrayTemp.filter(item => !jobsUnique.includes(item));
                    // console.log("frefrefre123", formArrayTemp);
                    // return { ...state, mainArray: [...formArrayTemp] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("formArray123", formArrayTemp);
    formArrayTemp.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.posiiton - b.position;
    });
    return { ...state, mainArray: formArrayTemp }
};
```

### Update

After researching this issue I came across this [issue #24206](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24206) in GitHub. There it states:

> There's a few things you aren't doing quite correctly here. Each time the render function runs you are creating a new array object for your data, so React has to rerender the entire list each time, you're renderItem function and keyExtractor function are also remade each rerender, and so the FlatList has to be rerun. You're also using the index for your key which means as soon as anything moves it will rerender everything after that point. I would recommend looking at what does/doesn't change when you rerun things (arrays, functions, object), and why the keyExtractor is important for reducing re-renders.

So I tried commenting `KeyExtractor` prop of `FlatList` and the issue got resolved. But this is causing issue in another form. How can I resolve that?